# Advice for interfacing strain gauges to PC

Tags: processing, arduino

I'm using an arduino to excitate and amplify strain gauges on a rod - the resulting voltage will be picked up by the analog inputs available on the arduino. I need to plot the 'torque' taken by that rod with respect to time on a graph, and the easiest way I see to do this is using the Processing language, as the basic arduino environment does not provide for graphical display.

Any tips on where to start? I only have prior experience with MATLAB, and a bit with Java.

EDIT: I should add a specific question - how do I assign a variable in Processing to the physical values read on the arduino (varying voltage through analog)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have experience with MATLAB, consider using the [ArduinoIO](http://www.mathworks.com/academia/arduino-software/arduino-matlab.html) API provided by The MathWorks. Basically lets you interface your Arduino to MATLAB - all the pin I/O features are available. So let MATLAB do the work plotting, etc, for you and just use your Arduino to collect your data.

I can personally vouch for how useful this API is. It's powering my master's thesis (building Arduino-powered vehicles and doing control on them).